# Add a copy of an object to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this code:

```
Element excludeFilterElementMerged = excludeFilter.elements.get(0);
for (model.rest.filter.Segment.Element elementExcl : excludeFilter.elements) {
    filterPosition++;
    excludeFilterElementMerged.isIncluded = "false";

    if (filterPosition % 10 == 0 || filterPosition == excludeFilter.elements.size()){
        elements.add(excludeFilterElementMerged);
        excludeFilterElementMerged = elementExcl;
    }

    excludeFilterElementMerged.filter.criteria.addAll(elementExcl.filter.criteria);
    excludeFilterElementMerged.filter.statement += " OR "+elementExcl.filter.statement;

}
```

After adding the `excludeFilterElementMerged` to the list, I would like to give it new attributes without affecting the object in the list. I thought, I would solve that by assigning it a new object: `excludeFilterElementMerged = elementExcl;`.

What is the right way to solve this?

Should I add a `clone` of the object to the `List`?  Or should I rather create a new object of type `Element`, put `excludeFilterElementMerged` inside and then save it to the `List`?

Comment: if `elementExcl` has a `clone` method you can try `excludeFilterElementMerged = elementExcl.clone();`

Comment: No it doesn't, it's my custom obj.

Comment: I believe you have to implement a `clone` method in you object

Comment: @luigonsec http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71

Comment: @m0skit0 it's right. Avoid clone it's recommended. You can create a copy constructors or static factory methods to copy the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`excludeFilterElementMerged = elementExcl` is definitely not the right way because that doesn't copy the object, it just creates a new reference to it.

There's no easy/simple way to copy an object in Java. You must either implement `clone()` ([which is not recommended](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71)) or better, have a copy constructor, e.g. `public Element(final Element anotherElement)`.

Comment: Plus one foe discouraging clone and recommending copy constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How should that constructor look if my object contains `muttable` attributes?

Comment: Highly depends on what those attributes are, but mostly `this.X = anotherElement.X`. Note that for data structures you will need to copy them, so the previous won't work.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing right now, it's quite lot of work as my object is complex. Contains `Lists` etc... So much manual work due to Java not being able to copy an object. It's very strange that it can't do it...

Comment: I don't know any other language that can copy objects right away, except maybe Clojure (but it uses immutable structures and classes are rarely used since it is mostly functional). And if you're having very complex classes, that it a symptom of bad design, e.g. [God class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). It's usually better to refactor big classes into smaller classes.

Comment: Actually I said it wrong. I have one class with 4 fields, one of the fields is list of another object/class, that contains 2 fields which are lists of objects etc. That model is taken from Eloqua (Oracle Business automation system), I haven't designed that ;)